# Запись одной строчкой

Tags: python, opencv

Хотелось бы узнать, как можно исправить этот код:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import os
from datetime import datetime


path = 'Training_images'
images = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)
print(myList)
for cl in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')
    images.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])
print(classNames)


def findEncodings(images):
    encodeList = []


    for img in images:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)
    return encodeList


def markAttendance(name):
    with open('Attendance.csv', 'r+') as f:
        myDataList = f.readlines()


        nameList = []
        for line in myDataList:
            entry = line.split(',')
            nameList.append(entry[0])
            if name not in nameList:
                now = datetime.now()
                dtString = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                date = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                f.writelines(f'\n{name},{dtString},{date}')

encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
print('Encoding Complete')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, -1)
# img = captureScreen()
    imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    facesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    encodesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, facesCurFrame)

    for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodesCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
        faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
# print(faceDis)
        matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)

        if matches[matchIndex]:
            name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
# print(name)
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = faceLoc
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1 * 4, x2 * 4, y2 * 4, x1 * 4
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2 - 35), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img, name, (x1 + 6, y2 - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            markAttendance(name)

    cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

**Вывод:** Запускается камера, для того чтобы зафиксировать лица людей (а если точнее, их появление в кадре) в отдельном файле,но записывает он не один раз, а подряд.
Т.е вот так:

```
NAME_SURNAME_11-41-05
NAME_SURNAME_11-41-05
NAME_SURNAME_11-41-05
...
NAME_SURNAME_11-41-05
NAME_SURNAME_11-41-06
```

Это, по идее, то, что нужно, но мне надо сократить количество этих выводов до одного на человека.

***Объясняю***: человек появился в кадре, программа распознала его лицо, записала в файле (ОДНОЙ СТРОЧКОЙ), и уже при следующем появлении этого человека она опять его распознает и запишет (опять же одной строчкой).

Answer (score 0):

Создайте хранилище для людей - сет или словарь (если какая ещё информация нужна).

Если человек найден, и он не в сете - добавить его, вывести в лог.

Если человек есть в сете, но не найден - убрать из сета. Возможно, на удаление лучше работать по нескольким кадрам, чтобы избежать "туда-сюда" из-за погрешностей распознавания (например, уменьшать счётчик в словаре)

Comment: Попробую, спасибо.